# Возможно ли отправить response без запроса?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Серверная часть на java, необходимо оповестить пользователя о событии на сервере и поменять кое-что на странице. В модели запрос ответ кажется нет такой возможности? У меня много пользователей (5-100) подключены к `jsp` странице при этом только один из них делает какие-то изменения (немного `js`) и остальные должны это увидеть в своих браузерах на той-же странице. Я могу средствами Java `Servlet API` решить эту задачу учитывая что объем обновляемых данных очень маленький строка из 2-ух символов. Или есть какие-то некостыльные способы решать эту задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Вам следует использовать механизм *веб-сокетов*, он позволяет отправлять данные на клиентскую часть без запроса с неё на сервер. Попробуйте для начала запустить [этот](http://dreamand.me/java/jee7-websocket-example/) пример, а затем приспособить его под свои задачи. Я вижу решение примерно таким:

- При открытии каждым пользователем страницы, создаётся веб-сокет и регистрируется на сервере;
- После внесения изменений серверная часть отсылает всем активным веб-сокетам некий сигнал, при получении которого в браузере, например, просто обновляется страница (либо выполняются другие нужные вам действия). "*поменять кое-что на странице*" можно будет JavaScript-ом.
- Не забывайте закрывать не используемые веб-сокеты, например, при получении сигнала закрытия сессии пользователя. [Вот пример](https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) слушателя событий сессий.

Готового решения с кодом дать не могу, т.к. у меня его нет, но Вы можете задавать на SO новые вопросы по возникающим проблемам.

Comment: Вы пропустили первую часть в слове *"веб-сокет"*

Comment: следуя из написанного механизм сокетов используется в коре, когда стартует сам веб-сервер..возможно `веб-сокет`?

Comment: и просто вразрер оставлю этот пост о том, что лучше использовать ajax ежели сокеты и почему -> [здесь][1]


  [1]: https://toster.ru/q/295830

Comment: @Dima Khodan - во-первых, в вопросе по указанной Вами ссылке нет однозначно верного ответа (по крайней мере, автор вопроса так и не выбрал правильный ответ). Во-вторых, предлагаемые ответы не противоречат моему ответу здесь, более того - скорее поддерживают его. У автора вопроса здесь ситуация, при которой клиенту надо получать сведения о изменениях. Два основных варианта сделать это - либо постоянно опрашивать сервер нагружая его (например, каждые 1-5 секунд), либо просто ожидать сообщения от сервера не выполняя никаких запросов до тех пор, пока не будет получено сообщение о изменении данных

Comment: @bobzer да первый пример очень похож на то что мне нужно спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Другими словами вам нужен "триггер". 
Если вы используете Spring в качестве фреймворка аннотация `@Schedule(cron = "* * * * * *")` поможет. Отправляете пачку данных джейсоном и со стороны `js` изменяете страницу с помощью `ajax` или можете к примеру использовать `angularJS`. 
Сама `JSP` не может изменяться динамически так как это страница которая формируется на сервере. 
Но вы можете добавить `ajax` запросы к `JSP` и тогда парсить вручную джейсон который приходит и вставлять в уже сгенерированный `html` (`jsp`). 
Но так же, если вам нужно переодически как-то изменять `UI` взависимости от действий на сервере и отправлять запрос, можете использовать `JavaRX`.

Comment: а если я на чистых сервлетах без спринга?

Comment: @Pavel на первой странице гугла выдало достаточно много примером. я думаю это можно найти спокойно когда знаете что искать.

Comment: В разрезе данной задачи AJAX не самый эффективный вариант. Изменения вносит только один пользователь, но при этом постоянный опрос сервера будут выполнять все 1-100 клиентов, причём им придётся делать это даже если изменений не было. Абсолютное большинство трафика и нагрузки на сервер будет использоваться вхолостую.

Comment: @bobzer что? вы похоже плохо понимаете как работает ajax и что это. когда вы используете ангуляр у вас тоже большое количесто трафика вхолостую идет? А под капотом там тот самый 'ajax'.

Comment: @Dima Khodan возможно есть способ не делать при помощи ajax лишних обращений но это подойдет для тех кто хорош в js а мне надо максимум логики переложить на java. Но спасибо, буду знать что ajax не прост и может не только в парадигмы запрос-ответ работать...